# HTML4.01でcanvasタグを使用する事は可能でしょうか。

Tags: html, html5-canvas

HTML4.01でcanvasタグを使用する事は可能でしょうか。

以下の記述でChart.jsを使用してグラフを描画する事が出来たのですが、canvasタグはHTML5から使用可能と思っております。

ご存じの方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授いただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
　<title>グラフ</title> 
</head>
<body>
  <h1>テストグラフ</h1>
  <canvas id="myBarChart"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myBarChart");
  var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['8月1日', '8月2日', '8月3日', '8月4日', '8月5日', '8月6日', '8月7日'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: '人数',
          data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 55, 65, 70],
          backgroundColor: "rgba(219,39,91,0.5)"
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: '人数数'
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            suggestedMax: 100,
            suggestedMin: 0,
            stepSize: 10,
            callback: function(value, index, values){
              return  value +  '人'
            }
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 今どき HTML 4.01 を宣言する意図は何ですか？

Answer (score 1):

質問文の中でも触れられているとおり、HTML 4.01 は canvas タグをサポートしていません。ブラウザによっては独自に解釈して表示することもあるでしょうが、仕様外です。

HTML5 が最初に勧告されたのは 2014 年です。現代的には HTML 4.01 を避けられるのであれば避けた方がベターです。HTML 4.01 に拘るのであれば、canvas タグを使わずに描画することになります。当然 Chart.js は使えないので、他の方法を使うことになるでしょう。

Comment: 加えて、HTML Standard では HTML 4.01 の DOCTYPE が許可されていないことにも注意が必要だと思います。